# Must learn classes for Java!

Tags: java

What would you consider the key/important classes for all java beginners to learn to grasp the funadamentals of the languag?

String, Array, Scanner, File, PrintWriter etc ?

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the very basic things like primitive types, the following come to mind.  This isn't complete, but these are the things that I find myself using most frequently

- Input/output with files and command line: `BufferedReader`/`BufferedWriter`/`Scanner`, etc.
- Java Collections Framework: All the `List`, `Set`, and `Map` classes
- Thread/Runnable: Beyond what the classes do, knowledge about deadlock, thread safety, and synchronization are all key.

Comment: Synchronization is important too

Comment: @TheLQ That's why I already mentioned it :)

Answer (score 5):

A good starting point is the trail in the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) on the [Essential Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/index.html).  From there you'll definitely branch off in different directions depending on what kind of programming you do.

Comment: Agreed.  Basic program writing implies knowing at least the contents of java.lang.* and java.io.*

Answer (score 0):

For Java Beginners I would suggest "Head First Java". The brain friendly mechanisms adopted by Head First folks helps the beginners learn, understand and remember the fundamentals clearly. HFJ focuses on most frequently used Java API.

fter a complete study of HFJ, I would strongly recommend Thinking in Java: Bruce Eckel --- IMO this is one of the greatest books on Java.